# Bootstrap: open images in modal with carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap Gallery: http://ba.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/galerie.html. What I need is for the full size images to open, perhaps in a Modal, when you click on the "Click" button.

> Is possible with Modal, or perhaps also with carousel?

**HTML:**

```
<section id="galerie" class="galerie">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/pics/1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p> 
                <a href="#">Click</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
</div>
</div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/pics/2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p> 
                <a href="#">Click</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
</div>
</div>

                <div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/pics/3.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p> 
                <a href="#">Click</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
</div>
</div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/pics/4.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p> 
                <a href="#">Click</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
</div>
</div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/pics/5.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p> 
                <a href="#">Click</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
</div>
</div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/pics/6.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
            <p> 
                <a href="#">Click</a>
            </p> 
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: where is click button?

Comment: when you with the mouse over the preview

Comment: you want a modal window when someone click on image? because i can not see any click button

Comment: hi you can try this [Lightbox for Bootstrap 3](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/)

Comment: @Siddharth yep, with the image in full size

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqw48agh/)

what i have done is i am showing   `modal` on `click` event of `img`, appending its html to modal body.

```
$(document).on('click','.img',function(){
    $('#modal .modal-body').html($('.img').clone()[0]);
  $('#modal').modal('show');
})
```

additional CSS

```
body .carousel-inner>.item>a>img, body .carousel-inner>.item>img{
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}

.img1{
  border:solid 1px red;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}

.img2{
  border:solid 1px green;
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
}
```

PS: i added border to image because loading image is pain in JSfiddle, it is just for the recognition of the image which is being clicked.